# Speechwriting: on topic or no?

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic-definition, specific-question

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/grooms-speech-any-suggestions) on writing a groom's speech does not quite seem on-topic.  We allow questions on writing such things as polite reminder e-mails and other fairly daily tasks, so it can't be the fact that the result isn't meant to be an enduring work of literature.  I can think in my head of questions about speech writing that I would probably instinctively think are on-topic.

So is speech writing in general on-topic?  If so, is the referenced question on-topic?  Does it need to be tightened somewhere?

Comment: Speechwriting itself should be on-topic; it just has as much technique as prose, poetry, or any other form of writing we do accept. As for whether that question in particular is a good fit, I'm on the fence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this question, IMHO, is that it's too broad. It doesn't present any particular problems or difficulties being faced; it just says "I'm writing [X], any advice on how to do that?".

In other words, this isn't a question, it's the "Please write me an essay on topic [X]" template. This is on-topic but a poor-quality question, unless OP can explain what actual problem needs solving.

Comment: I completely agree with Standback. We recently closed a question asking "How to write a short story?", and this is very similar.

Comment: So, aside from the issues with *this* specific question, I would say that "speech writing" is on topic.